# How to force Thunderbird to open link in Firefox under Gnome 3?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, gnome-3

I've found (after two hours of googling), how to force Gnome 3 to pass URL from Thunderbird to Firefox. There must be in short-cut to Firefox (e.g. file `~/.local/share/applications/alacarte-made.desktop`):

```
Exec=/usr/local/mozilla/firefox/firefox "%U"
```

The `%U` at the end of line should help, but it doesn't do, what I need. When I click on some link pointing to `http://barbucha.eu`, It is getting opened in Firefox:

```
file:///home/schnikow/'http://barbucha.eu/'
```

Argh... What's wrong yet? Is there some bug in Thunderbird v31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've workarounded it using a script, which extracts the sub-URL.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Gnome Shell desktop file spec, I see no reason why my file should work and yours should not.

I have `Exec=/home/username/bin/firefox/firefox %U` without double quotes around the `%U`.
I stumbled across this SO question while getting that working, and was curious if there's something else at play.
As far as I can tell, double quotes causes this weird and broken behavior.

It's safe to leave a url unquoted since any characters that could break the shell's parsing will be URL-encoded, but I can't tell you why this is the case.